# RHEL5 Bootable Kickstart DVD - Anaconda ignores my ks.cfg

Tags: linux, rhel5, automated-install, kickstart, anaconda

I have created a kickstart file, ks.cfg, which I wish to package with the RHEL5 install DVD. I extracted all the files from the DVD to a working directory '/root/cd':

```
cp -a /media/RHEL* /root/cd/
```

I also copied the ".discinfo" file when I realized it was missing:

```
cp /media/RHEL*/.discinfo /root/cd/
```

I copied the kickstart file to both the DVD's root directory and isolinux directory:

```
cp /root/ks.cfg /root/cd/
cp /root/ks.cfg /root/cd/isolinux/
```

I burn the disc using mkisofs:

```
mkisofs -o /root/custom_RHEL5_install.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
-c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
-R -J -v -T /root/cd/
```

Testing the new ISO file on a virtual machine, I boot with the following command:

```
linux ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg
```

The install DVD boots as if there is NO kickstart file and continues onto the graphical install environment of Anaconda. What am I missing to make this a silent automated install?

EDIT: Found the issue, it was an error in the kickstart. An error in the kickstart file will cause the installation to abort the kickstart and proceed with a manual install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was an error in the kickstart. An error in the kickstart file will cause the installation to abort the kickstart and proceed with a manual install.